# How to insert LESS mixin in to JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less

Is there any option to insert some LESS mixin in to JS code?

I have this border-radius mixin:

```
.border_radius(@radius: 5px) {
  border-radius: @radius;
  -moz-border-radius: @radius;
  -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
}
```

So is there any possible to add this mixin in to jQuery code?

```
var less = require('less');

$('.circle').css({
    width: width, height: width,
    less.border_radius(10px);
});
```

Comment: No. jQuery's `css()` function does not include a renderer for LESS.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define the JavaScript equivalent of the LESS mixins you require:

HTML

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

CSS

```
.circle { border: 1px solid #FF0000; }
```

jQuery

```
function border_radius(radius) {
  radius = radius || '5px';
  return {
    'border-radius': radius,
    '-moz-border-radius': radius,
    '-webkit-border-radius': radius
  }
}

var styles = border_radius(),
    width = '20px';
styles.width = width;
styles.height = width;

$('.circle').css(styles);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FsWLy/)

Comment: i will use this solution because it is simpler and writing and editing, thx

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you wanted, but maybe this trick would be helpful.
I do not see other way to use less's functions dynamically.

```
var parser = new less.Parser({});
var lessCode = '';
function roundedCorners(_class, radius) {
    lessCode = '/* import dependent syles */'
        + '@import "PATH-TO-YOUR-MAIN-LESS-FILE";'
        + '.' + _class + ' {'
            + '.rounded-corners(' + radius + 'px);'
        + '}';
    parser.parse(lessCode, function (error, root) { 
        $('head').append($( '<style type="text/css">' + root.toCSS() + '</style>' )); 
    });
}
//try...
roundedCorners('circle', 10);
```