# Get classname from tag in LESS

Tags: less

I want to use a classname to set a background on a element, but i'm not sure if it's possible with LESS js at the moment.

The case is:
I have a table with a list of athletes, on these lists i want to show a country flag as a background of a p tag.

In HTML it looks like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="athlete"><p class="us">Athlete 1</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to set the background image through a mixin, if i can get the classname from the P tag i would be there.

```
.athlete {
     p {
           .setBackgroundImage(@ClassName);

     }
}
```

is there anyway in LESS to achieve this?

Comment: You might prefer writing a JavaScript function that is equivalent to your mixin. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336695/how-to-insert-less-mixin-in-to-javascript-code

Comment: Good point, that gives me the flexibility i need.
I also tried to achieve this with a loop and an array, but that wasn't scaleable...
It could be a nice feature for future releases of LESS

Comment: I'm curious what was your "loop implementation" and why it was "not scalable". In Less you will have to explicitly define all possible athletes anyway since it has no notion of your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that i need a whole new rule for every possible country. My loop implementation didn't cut it either.

I went for the javascript implementation, i add a background image to a iso coded classname in a certain parent class.

```
<div class="nationality">
<p class="athlete">Athlete X<span class="nl"></span></p>
</div>

jQuery(".nationality span").css('background-image', 'url(../img/flags/60/'+jQuery(".nationality span").attr("class")+'.png);
```

Thanks guys.